# Tree with directory name and filenames

Tags: files, tree

I run with tree 1.7.0

```
tree -PF dat
```

It gives

```
.
├── 0deg/
├── 105deg/
├── 120deg/
├── 135deg/
├── 150deg/
├── 15deg/
├── 165deg/
├── 180deg/
├── 210deg/
├── 240deg/
├── 270deg/
├── 300deg/
├── 30deg/
├── 330deg/
├── 360deg/
├── 45deg/
├── 60deg/
├── 75deg/
└── 90deg/
```

where each folder contains a file `[directory-name].dat`. 
I would like have an output like

```
.
├── 0deg/0deg.dat 
├── 105deg/105deg.dat
...
```

I run the command

```
tree -Pf dat
```

and I get

```
.
├── ./0deg
├── ./105deg
├── ./120deg
├── ./135deg
├── ./150deg
├── ./15deg
├── ./165deg
├── ./180deg
├── ./210deg
├── ./240deg
├── ./270deg
├── ./300deg
├── ./30deg
├── ./330deg
├── ./360deg
├── ./45deg
├── ./60deg
├── ./75deg
└── ./90deg
```

I run the command

```
tree -Pf *.dat
```

and I get

```
.
├── ./0deg
├── ./105deg
├── ./120deg
├── ./135deg
├── ./150deg
├── ./15deg
├── ./165deg
├── ./180deg
├── ./210deg
├── ./240deg
├── ./270deg
├── ./300deg
├── ./30deg
├── ./330deg
├── ./360deg
├── ./45deg
├── ./60deg
├── ./75deg
├── ./90deg
└── ./rem_angle.dat
```

**How can you get such an output?**

Comment: why not using -f option - Prints the full path prefix for each file ?

Comment: If you want to simulate the behaviour you'd use find. In this case using GNUfind you could use the following `find . -type f -name '*.dat' -printf '|__ %P\n'`

Comment: Try this: tree -PFaf '*dat'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer using `tree` would be

```
tree -PF *.dat
```

You can also use (As I explained in my comment ) the `GNUfind` command.

```
find . -type f -name '*.dat' -printf '|__ %P\n'
```

You don't need GNU`find` though. You can also use the following which is posix.

```
find . -type f -name '*.dat' -print
```

Comment: My tree is 1.7.0 and I do not get expected output. I am trying to install the gnufind here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/179410/15504

Comment: This command **gfind . -type f -name '*.dat' -print** works the same as the BSD find.

Comment: @Masi, No idea how OSx labels those binaries. If `gfind` refers to GNU find, then you could use that. However, `-print` is posix and doesn't need `gfind`. You'd need `gfind` only if you use `-printf` which is a GNUism.